# CSS - Any Tip to remove the space?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need help to remove space above the navbar
[image: img]

My HTML code:
https://pastecode.io/s/uia7zv3t

My CSS code:
https://pastecode.io/s/ba5qtpmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .container class has 30px margin top and bottom, I believe that's what you meant.

Anyway, your body also has a margin you should reset, and you should use  tag in body to load CSS, but it should be moved to  instead.

Comment: Thank you, mate! Actually, I fixed it by changing the navbar position to relative. I will mark your answer as correct. ✌️